# Proof that a triangle can always be formed

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Alright so let's say a stick is broken into $n$ pieces with each breaking point chosen randomly and independently. If no piece is greater than $0.5$ in length, can a quadrilateral always be formed? That is to say for maybe $5$ pieces with no piece over $0.5$ in length is it possible to have no combination of the five pieces form a quadrilateral.

If so could you give me a reason or a proof for this, thanks.

Comment: what have you tried ? also your question title doesn't match it's content it's content is can an n-gon be formed.

Comment: Proof [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96617/determine-if-you-can-build-a-polygon-from-segments)

Comment: When you say $0.5$ in length, do you mean $0.5$ of the length of the stick?

Comment: @browngreen my first thought is it could be inches as well.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That's what it sounds like from the question, but it would seemingly be irrelevant since no other measurements are mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

No, one could not always form a quadrilateral. As a simple counter example consider a stick of total length 37, which is broken in to 5 parts $2+3+4+10+18=37$.
The longest part 18 is less than half of the total stick length, so the partition is allowed.

However, a side with 18 can not be used since the maximum combined length that can be obtained from the remaining pieces is $3+4+10=17 < 18$. But since $2+3+4=9<10$ also these four pieces can not form a quadrilateral.

Also with more pieces such partitions exist. You can use the following sequence
$1+2+4+8+\dots+2^n + (7*2^{n-2} +1)=15 *2^{n-2}$ for $n \geq 4$ for a construction of $n+2$ pieces. This sequence also does not allow a triangle to be formed.

An simple example of an "ultimate" sequence, however, is $2^1+2^2+2^3 + \dots + 2^n + (2^{n+1}-3) = 2^{n+2}-5$, because by using all of the pieces you could form a $(n+1)$-polygon, but no set of pieces can be used to form a triangle, quadrilateral, ..., $n$-polygon.